# Navigate horizontally and hit a button to go another layout vertically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-viewpager, android-scrollview

I've been trying to figure out how to go about doing this specific task, but I can't quite figure out.

So, I have a ViewPager setup with 2 layouts that work perfectly. In the landing Pager, I have a button. What I'd like to do is, hit that button and the page animate vertically (up) to another layout.

I got the similar movement with starting a new Activity, but the problem with that, is that the title bar gets animated as well. So it doesn't give this fluid motion to the layout above.

I tried several things, but came up short with a lot of crashes.

Then I was thinking of having the landing Pager be a ScrollView and stack both layouts on top of each other, and navigate to a specific id, but came to no avail.

Does what I'm saying making sense? How should I go about creating something like this?

So to summarize.

- Land on a page where you can swipe to one additional page (left).
- Be able to hit a Button (on landing page) and animate up (vertically) to another layout.
- All of this while having a static title bar.

Thanks in advance.